# How to select only corner vertices?

Tags: modeling

I'm cleaning up some edges and I want to get rid of excessive vertices:

[image: too many vertices]

Basically I want to be able to automatically select "important" vertices, these that define the geometry - corner vertices that I marked in the image. They have to stay.

Then I will be able to invert the selection and dissolve vertices that are occupying straight lines and do not add anything to overall shape.

Comment: You will be able to select them after using `X` > *Limited Dissolve*, however it will already dissolve "unimportant" verts leaving only basic shape. So no inverting selection and possibility to decide which one should be selected.

Comment: Although that does not answer the question directly, it does exactly what needs to be done, thanks.